# LimeSurvey custom result page

Tags: limesurvey

Is it possible to run an action in LimeSurvey that will send information about the completed survey to an external website?

I would like to create a page where I will display the result, I would also like to display external data from outside LimeSurvey there.

I thought to use the REST API to get the answer for that. I do not know how to connect it, i.e. the fact that the survey has been completed with the part responsible for retrieving the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check Remote Control 2?
https://manual.limesurvey.org/RemoteControl_2_API

> LimeSurvey RemoteControl 2 is a XML-RPC/JSON-RPC based web service
> available in LimeSurvey 2.0 or more recent which offers various API
> functions.
>
> LSRC2 makes it possible for developers to control specific
> functionality of LimeSurvey from any other application, without being
> restricted to PHP as a programming language.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I know how to get data via API. I don't know how to combine the fact that someone has completed the survey and is then redirected to the page with my custom result.

Comment: https://manual.limesurvey.org/URL_fields#End_URL_field

Comment: What if I don't want to redirect user to end_url, and just POST all survey content to another server?

Comment: You can do a plugin that uses the event AfterSurveyComplete (https://manual.limesurvey.org/AfterSurveyComplete) (need to review how to send the data, maybe with an API).

If not, on the end message you could create a form whose fields are filled with EM and then submitted by JavaScript.